# How to get individual fields in list of dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a list of dictionaries called `dictList` that has data like so:
`[{'id': '5', 'total': '39'}, {'id': '5', 'total': '43'}]`.

I am trying to create a new dictionary that uses the `id` as the key and `total` as the value.

So have tried this:

```
keys = [d['id'] for d in dictList]
values = [d['total'] for d in dictList]

new_dict[str(keys)]= values
```

However the output is: `{"['5', '5']": [39, 43]}`

I am not sure what is going on, I am just trying to get the id and the respective total like `5, 39` and `5, 43` in to `new_dict`.

EDIT:
Please note that `dictList` contains all the products with ID 5. There are other fields, but I didn't include them.

Comment: What would be the output, you have twice the id 5? dictionaries cannot have repeated keys

Comment: What do you want the output to be? A dictionary can only have _one_ value per key. Of course, that value could well be a _list_, which itself holds many elements, but the _dictionary key_ still has only one value -- the list.

Comment: I just want new_dict to contain all the productIDs and the respective totals.

Comment: so if there are multiple items with `id: 5` you want to sum their totals?

Comment: You need to tell us _exactly what `new_dict` should look like_. It is not clear what you want from your description of your expected output. A dictionary can only have one value per key, so `new_dict` can not have _two_ values for the `total` key. Your current list of dicts _already_ contains all the product ids and their respective totals.

Comment: as to why your current code doesn't work... the "set item" syntax for dicts like `new_dict[key] = value` sets a _single_ key and value in the dict.  with that in mind it is obvious why `new_dict[str(keys)]= values` gives `{"['5', '5']": [39, 43]}`

Comment: @efiemu Is this the output you want `{"5": [39, 43]}`?

Comment: Thank you, I see now. Since keys must be unique, there is probably no need for ```new_dict``` now. To get the sum of all ```total``` would I need to just loop through ```dictList``` ?

Comment: @Dani Mesejo if it is possible to get the sum of Total for product 5, that would be helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach:

```
data = [{'id': '5', 'total': '39'}, {'id': '5', 'total': '43'}]

res = {}
for d in data:
    key = d["id"]
    if key not in res:
        res[key] = 0
    res[key] += int(d["total"])

print(res)
```

**Output**

```
{'5': 82}
```

Alternative using [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
from collections import defaultdict

data = [{'id': '5', 'total': '39'}, {'id': '5', 'total': '43'}]

res = defaultdict(int)
for d in data:
    key = d["id"]
    res[key] += int(d["total"])

print(res)
```

**Output**

```
defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {'5': 82})
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `sorted` and `itertools.groupby` to group by the `'id'` key of each list element:

```
import itertools

dictList = [{'id': '5', 'total': '39'}, {'id': '10', 'total': '10'},
            {'id': '5', 'total': '43'}, {'id': '10', 'total': '22'}]

groups = itertools.groupby(sorted(dictList, key=lambda item: item['id'])
                           , key=lambda item: item['id'])
```

Next, take the sum of each group:

```
product_totals = {
    key: sum(int(item['total']) for item in grp)
    for key, grp in groups
}
```

Which gives:

```
{'10': 32, '5': 82}
```

---

If you have *lots* of such entries, you could consider using `pandas` to create a dataframe. Pandas has vectorized methods that help you crunch numbers faster. The idea behind finding the sum of totals is the same, except in this case we don't need to sort because [`pandas.groupby` takes care of that for us](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/groupby.html#groupby-sorting)

```
>>> import pandas as pd

>>> df = pd.DataFrame(dictList)
>>> df['total'] = df['total'].astype(int)
>>> df
   id total
0   5    39
1  10    10
2   5    43
3  10    22

>>> df.groupby('id').total.sum()
id
10    32
5     82
Name: total, dtype: int32

>>> df.groupby('id').total.sum().as_dict()
 {'10': 32, '5': 82}
```

Answer (score 0):

Although I'm not sure what you are trying to do, try this:

```
for d in dictlist:
    if new_dict[d["id"]]:
        new_dict[d["id"]] += d["total"]
    else:
        new_dict[d["id"]] = d["total"]
```

Comment: This overwrites the value with the value of the last element having that id. OP wants to sum the total for all elements having the same id

Comment: Oh you're right I read that wrong, just edited my answer.